# noob python regex all [A-Za-z] not inside '( )'

Tags: regex, python-2.7

Take it easy on me please I'm new to programming...

```
## example string below ##

x = 'Foo Foo (stuff) bar bar'


## current regex below ##

myre = re.compile(ur'([ A-Z ]+) ([(A-Z)]+)', re.UNICODE|re.IGNORECASE)

#----#

b = myre.findall(x)
```

### question

b returns exactly what I want which is.. **[(Foo, Foo), (bar, bar)]**. But I really have no idea why.. Or how.. Is this going to be reliable???

I'm trying to capture all chars in the [A-Za-z] set that are **NOT inside '()'**

Both 'Foo' and 'bar' could be multiple words separated by white space.

Also I'd rather the matched words be returned as a flat list rather than a list of tuples.

I'm open to any and all suggestions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot of stuff going on here. The `[...]` creates a character class which matches any single character or character range specified. The groups `(...)` are used to capture specific sub-patterns within the matched string. Note that `[(A-Z)]` is not a group; it is a character class that matches Latin letters or parentheses.

If all you're trying to do is return the substrings not inside parentheses, I'd recommend using `split` instead. For example:

```
re.split('\s*\(.*?\)\s*', 'Foo (stuff) bar') # => ['Foo ', ' bar']
```

Note, however, this will not handle nested parentheses:

```
 re.split('\s*\(.*?\)\s*', 'Foo (s(tuf)f) bar') # => ['Foo ', 'f) bar']
```

But it will handle multiple parenthetic groups:

```
 re.split('\s*\(.*?\)\s*', 'Foo (s) bar (s) baz') #=> ['Foo', 'bar', 'baz']
```

Comment: @user3204587 `\s` is a regex shorthand for 'any whitespace character', which includes spaces, tabs, newlines, etc.

Comment: thank you p.s.w.g your help is much appreciated. In your first example  the '\' in  "'\'("  is being used to say match the literal char '(' correct?

Comment: and thanks again. I'm new to stackoverflow as well. Didn't know that pushing enter inside the comment box will causes the comment to post..

Comment: @user3204587 Yes, that's correct. You can edit a comment within 5 minutes by clicking the `edit` link next to it.

Answer (score 0):

`(?<!\()\b([A-Z|a-z]+)\b(?!\))`

This will match all alpha-string words not enclosed by parentheses.  You could ignore case and reduce it to `(?<!\()\b([a-z]+)\b(?!\))`.  I'm not very familiar with python but I believe something like:

```
regex = re.compile(
    ur"""(?<!\()    # Negative look behind; preceeding character must not be open paren
    \b              # start/end word
    ([a-z]+)        # capture the alpha string
    \b              # start/end word
    (?!\))          # Negative look ahead; following character must not be close bracket""",
    re.VERBOSE|re.UNICODE|re.IGNORECASE)
```

([stolen and modified from Tim Pietzcker's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21611512/python-return-full-word-and-not-just-a-specfic-part-of-the-stringregular-expre))

Worth noting that this will throw away strings preceeded OR ended by the appropriate parenthesis (`foo (stuff bar` will only match `foo` and `bar` while `foo )stuff( bar` will match `foo` `stuff` and `bar`.

You can test with various input strings at [pythex](https://pythex.org).